# Visualize tree data

Tags: graphics, tree, visualization

I'm looking for a program to visualize a tree of data. It's small, with about 20 nodes. I'd like a graph suitable for a presentation in a vector graphics format such as pdf, svg, etc.

The input is a simple list of connected node pairs, like this:

```
specie,monosaccharide
specie,polysaccharide
specie,protein
specie,nucleic_acid
nucleic_acid,DNA
nucleic_acid,RNA
RNA,mRNA
RNA,ncRNA
```

Cytoscape seems too complex, Graphviz seems dead (website unresponsive), and Gephi won't even plot the first example in its tutorial.

I'd like to run the graphing program on my Mac, and I'm happy to write a small program, preferably Pyton or Perl, to generate the graph.

Recommendations please?

Answer (score 0):

It surprises me that the Graphviz website is not available, it should be something temporary. I would suggest that you represent your graph in python using [igraph](http://igraph.org/python/). See a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213956/plot-a-tree-like-graph-with-root-node-at-the-top) and as usual check the docs and a [tutorial](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html)