# igraph layout_reingold_tilford gives errors

Tags: igraph

I get the following error message when trying to use the  layout_reingold_tilford layout

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\igraph\layout.py", line 80, in **init**
    self._coords = [list(coord) for coord in coords]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I have found the following question which has a simple question and answer but when I try the example I get the same error

[Plot a tree-like graph with root node at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213956/plot-a-tree-like-graph-with-root-node-at-the-top)

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph(n = 12, directed=True)
g.add_edges([(1,0),(2,1), (3,2), (4,3),
         (5,1),
         (6,2), (7,6), (8,7),
         (9,0),
         (10,0), (11,10)])
g.vs["label"] = ["A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "F", "C", "B", "D", "C", "D", "F"]
layout = g.layout_reingold_tilford(mode="in", root=0)
ig.plot(g, layout=layout)
```

Comment: Yes, making root iterable works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [C implementation](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/src/graphobject.c#L6973) of this function, `root` is considered to be in iterable **only**, however the [documentation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#layout_reingold_tilford) is a bit confusing: "the index of the root vertex or root vertices".

Try to use `root=[0]` instead.